# Call order of jQuery ready callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, onreadystatechange

If have two javaScript functions in a page which are required to be called when document load is complete. Is is possible that any function can executed first or it will be the first function which is executed first always?

So if using jQuery if you have following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ function1(); });

$(document).ready(function(){ function2(); });
```

Can it happen that `function2` is executed first or will `function1` always be executed first ?

Comment: Your script will be read and executed line by line

Comment: This got nothing to do with pure JavaScript, it's 100% dependent on how  jQuery implement the `$(document).ready()` method.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - That's not the question. He basically wants to know the rules of event queuing (if any).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery ready uses the [Deferred object system](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) :

```
ready: function( fn ) {
    // Add the callback
    jQuery.ready.promise().done( fn );

    return this;
},
```

(from the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js))

And the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done) states that

> Callbacks are executed in the order they were added

So yes, your callbacks will be executed in order of addition.

Answer (score 3):

If you want these functions to be executed in order, why don't you just write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    function1();
    function2();
});
```

Comment: "I think it is possible, because the ready event is called asynchronusly" : That's just wrong. JQuery ensures the order of execution is the order of addition (see my answer).

Comment: I cant have these functions together because they are based on separate events in the page. so its possible that none of them, one of them or both of them appear in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Better make use of callback function to be sure about the execution order of the functions

Comment: What you mean by "use callback function"? How is it relevant here?