# jquery document.ready multiple declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I realized that I can specify `$(document).ready(function(){});` more than once. 
Suppose like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var abc = "1122";
    //do something..
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var abc = "def";
    //do something..
});
```

1. Is this standard ?
   Those codes work on my FF (16.0.2).  I just a little afraid that other browser may not.
2. What actually happen ? How jQuery handle those code ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1327766/122005) out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's standard and recommended and jQuery guarantees those functions will be executed in order of declaration (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797257/call-order-of-jquery-ready-callback/12797330#12797330) for details regarding the implementation).

The `abc` variable are local to your functions and don't interfere. You cannot see the value of `abc` declared in one of the callbacks from the other one.

Comment: Just to add, the main reason this is handy is to allow you to specify `load` handlers in multiple `js` files so you can keep your code compartmentalised.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan +1 for an advice I 100% agree with.

Comment: yes, I actually implemented load + multiple js now. Now just curious, can I get the `var abc` in the first declaration (which the value is "1122") without delcaring the `var abc` globally ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question but if you want to get in the second callback the value of abc declared in the first callback, then you should declare it as `window.abc="1122";`.

Comment: @dystroy yes, that's what I wanted to do. But I've too many multiple js files (with document.ready function each), and some have same variables name inside. Declaring globally like `window.abc` will make it unique, and won't work in my case. I wanted to get certain `var abc` in certain document.ready block. Is it feasible ?

Comment: No. You can't get a local variable declared in a function if you don't make an accessor (eg `window.getAbc=function(){return abc}`). In most big applications we use space names to avoid problems : `window.myapp.mymodule = {abc:"1212"};`.

Comment: @dytroy Thx a lot dystro for the explanation. ~

Answer (score 1):

Yes, multiple document.ready function can be used in the same page. It will not going to give any error or exception in any browser. and the function will be executed for upper to lower order.

Comment: "upper to lower" is different from the order in which they were called, which is the true order they will execute

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's standard, I'd rather use only one $(document.ready) ... to keep it DRY, otherwise you may end up with let's say 10 of these declarations on your page, which will make it look like unmaintanable spaghetti code (but JS allows you to do that too)

Comment: yeah, I actually did that. But then my codes gets more and more lines. After reaching over than > 1k lines, I finally stop and split into multiple js files. With combination of `load` method off course, its become pretty neat now.