# How to bind jquery function to specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make function working only on page with specified element.
I have search page, search fields and results are in `search-block` div.
I want to bind function to this block, so function will not work on other pages (without `<div id='search-block>...</div>`)

I have next js code atm:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    // instructions for another page (handlers for some links)

    $(function(){
        setInterval(findSomething,1000);
    });     
});
```

It working fine on page with `search-block` div, but it works fine on the other pages too. Browser tries to run this function on all other pages. I don't need this.

I tried jquery bind, but it now worked for me, don't know why :(

```
$("#search-block").bind(function(){
    setInterval(findSomething,1000);
});
```

How I can bind handler to speciges too.fied block?

Comment: You may want to load "search-block" special js code only on the page with the $("search-block"), so you'll be sure that $("search-block") is exist.

Comment: How I can do this? If I will use it in such way strange error appearing . Smth like `$0"$search-block")` — illegal character there (0). I can't use `$(document).ready(function(){ ... }` in this script, because I already used it in another script.

Comment: Well, you can use multiple `$().ready()` (read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797257/call-order-of-jquery-ready-callback/12797330#12797330) for additional information). Regarding to your question, I'd move all "search" logic to `search-block.js` and insert `<script src="search-block.js"></script>` to the page with $("search-block") object on. BTW you may want to read about something like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) or about any modular design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of bind you have to check for the length of that elem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('#search-block').length > 0){ // <---checks the availability
       setInterval(findSomething,1000);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind is always used with an event to bind to:

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "mouseenter mouseleave", function() {

});
```

if you want to execute that only when the block is available on the page, use this:

```
if ($('#search-block').length) {
    setInterval(findSomething,1000);
}
```

This checks the number of times #search-block is found on the page and if it is not 0(false) it executes the code.

Comment: Your second one is better.